# Maxima missing obvious simplifications

Tags: simplify, maxima, simplification

I'm developing some equations to go on a embedded controller, and thus trying to reduce them to the simplest (fewest terms) possible. Unfortunately, what wxmaxima is spitting out is nearly half a page long, for each of the 5 equations I need. What irritates me is that their are obvious simplifications that I cannot get wxmaxima to perform. For example:

```
-8*m5*sin(Te)*Te'^2*L1^2-8*m4*sin(Te)*Te'^2*L1^2
```

could be reduced to:

```
-8*sin(Te)*L1^2*Te'^2*(m4+m5)
```

Again, this is one **small** part of a long expression filled with similar potential simplifications. ALL variables are real constants except for the Te, Ts, and Tw terms, which include Te', Te" etc..., which are real variables. I've tried factor (doesn't work if applied to whole expression) radcan, ratsimp, fullratsimp, combine, collectterms, but nothing seems to work. One of the expressions is below, you need the following declares to allow the apostrophe and double quote to be used as part of a variable:

```
declare("w'", alphabetic)$
declare("e'", alphabetic)$
declare("s'", alphabetic)$
declare("w\"", alphabetic)$
declare("e\"", alphabetic)$
declare("s\"", alphabetic)$
```

here is one of the full expressions:

```
(2*m5*Ts"*L2^2-m5*Te"*L2^2+8*m5*cos(Te/2)*Te'*Ts'*L1*L2+16*m5*sin(Te/2)*Ts"*L1*L2-4*m5*cos(Te/2)*Te'^2*L1*L2-8*m5*sin(Te/2)*Te"*L1*L2-2*m5*pcx5*sin(Tw)*Tw'^2*
L2-4*m5*pcx5*Ts'*sin(Tw)*Tw'*L2+2*m5*pcx5*Te'*sin(Tw)*Tw'*L2+2*m5*pcx5*cos(Tw)*Tw"*L2+4*m5*pcx5*Ts"*cos(Tw)*L2-2*m5*pcx5*Te"*cos(Tw)*L2+16*m5*sin(Te)*Te'
*Ts'*L1^2+16*m4*sin(Te)*Te'*Ts'*L1^2+8*m3*sin(Te)*Te'*Ts'*L1^2-16*m5*cos(Te)*Ts"*L1^2-16*m4*cos(Te)*Ts"*L1^2-8*m3*cos(Te)*Ts"*L1^2+16*m5*Ts"*L1^2+16*m4*Ts"*L1^2+
10*m3*Ts"*L1^2+2*m2*Ts"*L1^2-8*m5*sin(Te)*Te'^2*L1^2-8*m4*sin(Te)*Te'^2*L1^2-4*m3*sin(Te)*Te'^2*L1^2+8*m5*cos(Te)*Te"*L1^2+8*m4*cos(Te)*Te"*L1^2+4*m3*cos(Te)*Te"*
L1^2-8*m5*Te"*L1^2-8*m4*Te"*L1^2-8*m3*Te"*L1^2+4*m5*pcx5*cos((2*Tw+Te)/2)*Tw'^2*L1-4*m5*pcx5*cos((2*Tw-Te)/2)*Tw'^2*L1+8*m5*pcx5*Ts'*cos((2*Tw+Te)/2)*Tw'*L1-4*m5*pcx5*Te'*
cos((2*Tw+Te)/2)*Tw'*L1-8*m5*pcx5*Ts'*cos((2*Tw-Te)/2)*Tw'*L1+4*m5*pcx5*Te'*cos((2*Tw-Te)/2)*Tw'*L1+4*m5*pcx5*sin((2*Tw+Te)/2)*Tw"*L1-4*m5*pcx5*sin((2*Tw-Te)/2)*Tw"*L1+8*m5*
pcx5*Ts"*sin((2*Tw+Te)/2)*L1-6*m5*pcx5*Te"*sin((2*Tw+Te)/2)*L1+4*m5*pcx5*Te'*Ts'*cos((2*Tw+Te)/2)*L1-3*m5*pcx5*Te'^2*cos((2*Tw+Te)/2)*L1-8*m5*pcx5*Ts"*sin((2*Tw-Te)/2)*L1+2*m5*
pcx5*Te"*sin((2*Tw-Te)/2)*L1+4*m5*pcx5*Te'*Ts'*cos((2*Tw-Te)/2)*L1-m5*pcx5*Te'^2*cos((2*Tw-Te)/2)*L1+8*m3*pcx3*sin(Te)*Te'*Ts'*L1+4*m2*pcx2*sin(Te)*Te'*Ts'*L1+8*m4*
pcx4*cos(Te/2)*Te'*Ts'*L1-8*m3*pcx3*cos(Te)*Ts"*L1-4*m2*pcx2*cos(Te)*Ts"*L1+16*m4*pcx4*sin(Te/2)*Ts"*L1+4*m3*pcx3*Ts"*L1-4*m3*pcx3*sin(Te)*Te'^2*L1-2*m2*pcx2*
sin(Te)*Te'^2*L1-4*m4*pcx4*cos(Te/2)*Te'^2*L1+4*m3*pcx3*cos(Te)*Te"*L1+2*m2*pcx2*cos(Te)*Te"*L1-8*m4*pcx4*sin(Te/2)*Te"*L1+2*m5*pcx5^2*Tw"+2*Izz5*Tw"+2*m1*
pcy1^2*Ts"+2*m5*pcx5^2*Ts"+2*m4*pcx4^2*Ts"+2*m3*pcx3^2*Ts"+2*m2*pcx2^2*Ts"+2*m1*pcx1^2*Ts"+2*Izz5*Ts"+2*Izz4*Ts"+2*Izz3*Ts"+2*Izz2*Ts"+2*Izz1*Ts"-
(m5*pcx5^2+m4*pcx4^2+2*(m2*pcx2^2+Izz2)+Izz5+Izz4)*Te")/(2)
```

Comment: Have you tried: `trigsimp`, `trigrat` and `trigreduce`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
load (scifac);
declare("`", alphabetic);
expr: (-8*m5*sin(Te)*Te`^2*L1^2-8*m4*sin(Te)*Te`^2*L1^2);
gcfac(expr);
                                                 2   2
(%o2)                   - 8 (m5 + m4) sin(Te) Te`  L1
```

I use ` (backtick) not ' (apostrophe).

Maybe [optimize](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_6.html#IDX219) can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether or not my method is standard, but whenever I do a computation in maxima i use the command

```
ratsimp();
```

so in your example I would have done

```
load(scifac)$
declare("`", alphabetic)$
ratsimp(-8*m5*sin(Te)*Te'^2*L1^2-8*m4*sin(Te)*Te'^2*L1^2);
```

this generates the output

```
(-8*m5-8*m4)*sin(Te)*Te`^2*L1^2
```

I used the backtick as well, but only because I believe ' is reserved; and, after declaring backtick, I didn't have to declare all of the variables.